# Download large file in ASP.NET WebAPI with AngularJS and IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

in my ASP.NET WebAPI I am providing a link to my file whcih I want to download. Although I modified the web.config to server larger files with

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="2097152" />
```

I get a Out Of Memory Exception even if I enter the filepath in the adressbar of my browser. Why cant the server serve large files? What am I missing? As a result of the WebAPI-Method I give back the path and then doing a link the user can click.

BR

Tenoda

Comment: Can you post the code that serves the file itself?  Are you using [Response.Buffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526001(v=vs.90).aspx)=true?

Comment: Well the code is not spectacular, as it only gives me back a link to the file on a folder I copied the file to.

Comment: `[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Export(ExportDefinitionViewModel exportDefinitionViewModel)
{
 //...
 return Ok(ModelWithMyPathAsProperty);
}`

Comment: What code is throwing an OutOfMemoryException?  Or are you seeing this in the event logs?  Are you seeing an HTTP 500 in the browser?  Please describe the details of the symptom.

Comment: If enter the file file link in the Browser, it runs a moment and then shows me the yellow screen of death saying that it ran out of memory. I am missing some IIS setting I gues...